# Using boost with DevC++: compiler set validation error

Tags: c++, boost

So I want to use the boost headers with DevC++ without having to manually configure the include directories each time. The problem I'm having is that I'll go under Compiler Options and add C:\Program Files\boost_1_56_0 to the includes, but when I, say, close out of DevC++ and open it again, it tells me that the directory "does not exist", even though it clearly does, as it allowed me to use the boost headers perfectly with my program before I closed out of DevC++!

I figure the problem is due to whatever faculty DevC++ uses to validate compiler sets, like maybe that it isn't looking in the right place to validate the directory? But even if that is the case I have no idea how to get that faculty to look where I want it to. I dunno ... any help on this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Active development for DevC++ stopped maybe 5 years ago and maybe more. It's no longer being supported either as far as I'm aware. If this is a bug, there is nobody to fix it. Unless you want to do it yourself, that is.

I recommend using a different editor, geany, notepad++, eclipse etc.